# Why is dict(zip(list1, list2)) adding extra escape characters?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, python-re

I am zipping two lists into a dictionary using `dict(zip(list1, list2))`

`list2` contains escape characters generated through:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

data = pd.read_table(file, sep = '\t', usecols = ['list1', 'list2'], error_bad_lines=False)
data['list2'] = data['list2'].map(re.escape)

data
        list1                                    list2
0      c100001_g1_i1    mRNA::jcf7190000025784:336550\-338439\(\-\)
1      c100003_g1_i1      mRNA::jcf7190000164685:24994\-31705\(\+\)
```

When I attempt to create a dictionary, extranneous escape characters are introduced:

```
data_dict = dict(zip(data.list1, data.list2))

data_dict
{'c99999_g2_i2': 'mRNA::jcf7190000086075:207510\\-229401\\(\\-\\)', 'c99999_g2_i3': 'mRNA::jcf7190000086075:207510\\-229401\\(\\-\\)'}
```

How can I get the extraneous escape characters to stop being introduced? What am I doing that is invoking these extra escape characters into the dictionary?

Comment: It's not adding any extra characters. That's just how strings with escape characters are shown when you print a list or dict.

Comment: Do `print(data_dict['c99999_g2_i2'])` and you won't see them.

Comment: @Barmar thank you. Why does `for value in data_dict.values(): print(value)` show the format I'm looking for, but `print(data_dict.values())` does not?

Comment: Because `print()` prints the `str()` of its arguments. The string of a dictionary contains the `repr()` of its elements.

Comment: `str.__repr__()` wraps quotes around the value and escapes special characters in it. It's showing what you would have to type as a literal.

Comment: @Barmar when I don't escape the characters using `map(re.escape)` and zip the two lists together, the `repr()` of its elements show zero backslashes as opposed to two backslashes from the current example. Shouldn't I see a single backslash in the unescaped version given your explanation?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the call to `re.escape()`. That's adding literal backslashes. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Barmar It's for some downstream stuff w/ making file names/snakemake wildcards (or that's my plan for now at least)

Comment: So `re.escape` changes a single backslash to a double backslash. Then if you print the representation of that, you get 4 backslashes.

Comment: @Barmar I'm only getting two backslashes with this current method. If I don't use `re.escape` I get zero backslashes. I want one backslash.

Comment: In this case, it's not escaping backslash, it's escaping `-` and `(` because these have special meaning in a regular expression. So `-` becomes `\-`, and when you print the representation of that it becomes `\\-`

Comment: As I said in my first comment, there's really only one backslash before `-`. The doubled backslash is just from the way you're viewing the string.

Comment: Yes, so I'm just curious why the representation doesn't show `\-` for the unescaped version if this is how dictionaries print their values? (Does this make sense?)

Comment: The unescaped version looks like `{'c99999_g2_i1': 'CDS::jcf7190000086075:219024-220595(-)', 'c99999_g2_i2': 'mRNA::jcf7190000086075:207510-229401(-)'}` but shouldn't single backslashes exist here? (given the reasoning for having two backslashes above)

Comment: The whole purpose of `re.escape()` is to add backslashes before any characters that have special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: Yes (that is my purpose for escaping the characters). I'm confused why it's ZERO or TWO backslashes printed, and never ONE backslash if the representation of its elements shows what you have to type as a literal?

Comment: `re.escape()` adds 1 backslash. `repr()` converts every backslash into 2 backslashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240975/discussion-between-barmar-and-anita).

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way that dictionaries are printed that gives that behaviour. to see the *real* output, you should print every individual key and value, see if it still "adds" extra backslashes.